# Applying DataAnnotation validations for front end but not backend

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

`[RegularExpression(@"^\d+.\d{0,2}$", ErrorMessage = "Tax rate can't have more than 2 decimal places")]
        public double TaxRate { get; set; }`

Using Entity Framework as the ORM along with Data Annotations on themodels. The above validation works for the front end where it doesn't allow the user to input things like `10.255` since we're only allowing for two decimal places. But we'd like to store the data in our database after dividing the input by 100. So an input of `10.25` would be saved as `.1025`. But because we have the above validation, we're getting an error on save.

Is there a way to have the data annotations enforce validation for the front end but not on save?

Comment: create a view model and put the validations on it.

Comment: Thanks @Fran I'll probably end up going with that.